# How to implement a generic serde_json::from_str

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am trying to write a generic code that reads a `json` file into an object. But it seems that there is something I am missing here.

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, io::Read};

pub fn from_file<'a, T>(filename: String) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: Deserialize<'a>,
{
    let mut file = File::open(filename)?;
    let mut content: String = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut content)?;
    Ok(serde_json::from_str::<T>(&content)?)
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
error[E0597]: `content` does not live long enough
  --> src\util\file.rs:11:34
   |
4  | pub fn from_file<'a, T>(filename: String) -> Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>
   |                  -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
11 |     Ok(serde_json::from_str::<T>(&content)?)
   |        --------------------------^^^^^^^^-
   |        |                         |
   |        |                         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |        argument requires that `content` is borrowed for `'a`
12 | }
   | - `content` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `flavour` due to previous error
```

What I understand is that I have to bound `T`, thanks for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283800/serde-jsonfrom-str-error-where-string-from-file). But I am uncertain which bounds to add.

And how to infer the required bounds for such problems. I tried to read `from_str` and found that it requires `T: de::Deserialize<'a>` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime argument to [`Deserialize<'de>`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.144/serde/de/trait.Deserialize.html) indicates the lifetime of the data you're deserializing *from*. For efficiency reasons, serde is allowed to borrow data straight from the structure you're reading from, so for example if your JSON file contained a string and the corresponding Rust structure contained a `&str`, then serde would *borrow* the string directly from the JSON body. That means that the JSON body, at least for `Deserialize`, has to live at least as long as the structure deserialized from it, and that length of time is captured by the `'de` lifetime variable (called `'a` in your example).

If you want to read data without borrowing anything from it, you're looking for [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.144/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html). From the docs,

> ## Trait `serde::de::DeserializeOwned`
>
> A data structure that can be deserialized without borrowing any data from the deserializer.
>
> This is primarily useful for trait bounds on functions. For example a `from_str` function may be able to deserialize a data structure that borrows from the input string, but a `from_reader` function may only deserialize owned data.

So if your bound is `DeserializeOwned` (which is really just `for<'de> Deserialize<'de>`), then you can read data from the string *without* borrowing anything from it. In fact, since you're reading from a file, you can use [`from_reader`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/de/fn.from_reader.html), which does so directly, and you don't even have to worry about the intermediate string at all.